# Why I cant connect to database if I have volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have next `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: './Docker/apache-php/'
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dmm
      MYSQL_USER: dmm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

That works nice. I can connect to database from webserver using `db:3306` adress.

But if I add any volume to db container like

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: './Docker/apache-php/'
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dmm
      MYSQL_USER: dmm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql/
```

`db:3306` refuses all conections

Whats wrong?

Comment: Probably an error. Check the docker logs for the container?

Comment: do you have db folder in your host system?

Comment: 1) Logs: Webserver just cant resolve names, database dont see any connections

2)Yes, I have /db/ folder.

Comment: Try adding `container_name : db` for db service.

Comment: This doesnt help

Comment: Paste your docker logs of db container.